# for loop and function in R/Rstudio - I'm keep getting errors & graph not displaying correctly

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, cjk

-------------------------------Given Code---------------------------------

```
# Function to generate coin flips n times and determine the longest run of
# heads or tails.

longest.run<-function(n)
{
  # generate n Bernoulli trials with success probability 1/2
  x<-rbinom(n,1,.5)
  #
  # determine the longest run
  # compute successive differences
  #
  diffs<-diff(x)
  #
  # determine where difference is 1 or -1
  #
  change.positions<-seq(1:n-1)[abs(diff(x))==1]
  #
  # insert change positions at the ends (0 and n)
  #
  change.positions<-c(0,change.positions,n)
  #
  # return the maximum difference between change positions
  #
  x
  max(diff(change.positions))
}


# Create a vector with value 100 repeated 10,000 times

x<-rep(100,10000)

# Apply the longest run function to each element of x

longest.runs<-sapply(x,longest.run)

# Estimate the expected value using the average of the longest.runs vector
#
mean(longest.runs)
```

------------------------------Given Code---------------------------------

So my task is 
(1) to get an approximation to the expected value of the length of the longest run in n flips of a fair coin
for n = 10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60; 70; 80; 90; 100; ... 250:

(2) then I have to plot the expected value vs. n and  fit a curve of the form y = clog(n) for some c to the data.

(3) Lastly, I have to use that fit to predict the expected value when n = 500:

Then approximate the value you get using
simulation and compare.

What I have right now is

```
longest.run <- function(n){
  + x <- rbinom(n ,1, .5)
  + diffs <- diff(x)
  + change.positions <- seq(1:n-1)[abs(diff(x))==1]
  + change.positions <- c(0, change.positions, n)
  + max(diff(change.positions))
}

expected.values <- c() 
variance.values <- c()

n <- seq(10, 250, 10)

for (i in 1:25){
  + x <- rep(n[i], 10000)
  + longest.runs <- sapply(x, longest.run) 
  + expected.values[i] <- mean(longest.runs)
  + variance.values[i] <- var(longest.runs)
}

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(n, expected.values, xlab = "expected.values")
plot(n, variance.values, xlab = "variance.values")

curve(c*log(x),add = TRUE)
```

I getting an error

+x <- rep(n[i], 10000) でエラー:  (error here) 
   関数 "+<-" を見つけることができませんでした (can't find the variable "+<-")

I think this is because of the for loop...

also, I'm getting exactly the same graph for two graphs (which should be different) ...

Any idea?

Comment: remove the leading `+`

Comment: didn't work. do you see any other errors in the code?